# How to launch view controllers before UITabBarController?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app/game where I would like to display a series of view controllers (ie: Start game, load game, etc) before displaying any form of UITabBarController.

The process would be:

1. Launch app delegate
2. Launch my series of view controllers
3. Only when Start game has been pressed launch/show the UITabBarController.

My UITabBarController is tied to the app delegate, and my current code is as such:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    SplashScreenVC *splashScreenVC = [[SplashScreenVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashScreenVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


    UINavigationController *firstView = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [firstView presentModalViewController:splashScreenVC animated:NO];
    [firstView release];


    [splashScreenVC release];
    [self.window addSubview:[tabController view]];
    return YES;
}
```

I try to launch the splash screen as a modal view controller, but this does not appear to work.

I've also tried launching it as `initWithRootViewController` -- but regardless what I do the UITabBar still gets launched and I never see the modal view.

So, how do I launch stuff, views, etc before the tabBarController view?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the tabbar hidden?

Comment: I'll research that to see if that'll work.  Ideally though I'd to tell the app delegate to launch certain views before the tab view controller; but if that doesn't work I'll just try your idea of hiding the tab bar and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: You can actually do another thing... Just add your ViewController's view to the window after you added the tabbar. When you don't need them anymore, just: [self.view removeFromSuperview]; The ViewController's view will be in front of the tabbar, so you don't need to worry about setting it to invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the iOS responder chain ?  If you want to show the UI , the UI must be added on the  window .
so the splash should be added on the window( the first index on top just "tabbar hidden"), you will see the display effect, then after showing Splash , you will see the normal tabbar.

note:

1. `[self.window bringSubviewToFront:self.splashView];`  // on the top
2. `[self performSelector:@selector(removeSplashView) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];` // after 5s the splash will disappear automatically